# Swift 3 Iterate Over Array of Classes

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to translate the following code to Swift 3. I feel like other posters have answered this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
- (BOOL)allowTouchForSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    NSArray *classes = @[[UITextField class], [UISearchBar class], [UITextView class]];
    for (Class class in classes) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:class]) {
            return YES;
        }
        if ([subview.superview isKindOfClass:class]) {
            return YES;
        }
    };
    return NO;
}
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
func allowTouchForSubview(subview: UIView) -> Bool {
    let allowedClasses: [AnyClass] = [UITextField.self, UISearchBar.self, UITextView.self]
    for classType in allowedClasses {
        if subview is classType {
            return true
        }
        if let superview = subview.superview {
            if superview is classType {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

It errors on both references to `classType` and says 'use of undeclared type classType'. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    func allowTouchForSubview(subview: UIView) -> Bool {
         let allowedClasses: [AnyClass] = [UITextField.self, UISearchBar.self, UITextView.self]

    for classType in allowedClasses {
        if subview.isKind(of: classType)  || (subview.superview?.isKind(of: classType) ?? false) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false 
}
```

to test:

```
let test = UITextView()
allowTouchForSubview(subview: test)//prints true

let textField = UITextField()
allowTouchForSubview(subview: textField)//prints true


let subview = UIView()
allowTouchForSubview(subview: subview) //prints false
test.addSubview(subview)
allowTouchForSubview(subview: subview) //prints true
```

Comment: This appears to work. Any idea why 'is' wasn't working - or what the difference between is and isKindOf is really doing?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with bridging. .kind(of:_) seems like it's using dynamic dispatch to resolve the type of the instance.